# On bijectivity of $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ via $f(n) = n^3+1$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> Let $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ via $f(n) = n^3+1$. Is the function bijective?

Injective: Suppose $f(a) = f(b) $

$$\implies a^3 +1 = b^3 +1 \implies a^3 =b^3\implies a=b$$
Hence, $f$ is injective.

Surjective: We know that $n \ge 1 \implies n^3 \ge 1$ 
How do I prove its surjective or not?

Comment: Try to solve $f(n)=3.$

Comment: @mfl $ \sqrt[3]{2}$ so its not surjective since $ \sqrt[3]{2} \notin N$

Comment: Right. So you have got the answer to your question.

Comment: Little nitpick: it should be $f(n) = n^3 + 1$.

Comment: Or also try to solve $f(n)=1$. This will depend on whether or not you include $0$ in natural numbers. Different authors either include or don't include $0$ in natural numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

$$f(n)=n^3+1\geq 1+1=2$$ Thus, $1$ doesn't have  a pre-image. Hence, $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Natural numbers may include $0$ depending on your definition. Different authors either include or don't include $0$ in natural numbers.

Comment: @user236182 Agreed. OP's definition doesn't include $0$. If you read his attempt at surjectivity, it says "$n \geq 1.$"

Answer (score 1):

> HINT:
>   Cube of any natural number is of the form $7k$ or $7k\pm1.$

Answer (score 0):

A function $f:E\mapsto F$ is surjective, if and only if :

$$\forall y\in F, \exists x \in E : y=f(x)$$

Here, $E=F=\mathbb{N}$ and $f(x) = x^3+1$

You can easily see that $\nexists x \in \mathbb{N} : f(x) = 0 $ since $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}, x^3+1 \ge 1$

Hence $f$ is not surjective.

As a side note, if the domain of definition is $f : \mathbb{N}^+ \mapsto \mathbb{N}^+$ then it is the same as before, since $\forall x \in \mathbb{N}^+,f(x) \ge 2$ we can see that $y=1$ has no antecedent.